# Circuit that takes input signal and controls led

Tags: microcontroller, led, timer, pulse

I am trying to design a circuit that compares a recorded signal to a stock signal. If they are not similar it then inputs a signal into a circuit which will change the pulse of the led to stimulate a channel until these signals are relatively similar. (Feedback loop) It will take a input that (changes the frequency) in which the led pulses. Any help is great.

Comment: You mean like a PLL?

Comment: What do you mean by similar? Frequency, waveshape, amplitude, etc.